# Program to create array for unique binary sequence

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, sequence

I'm trying to create multiple 2D arrays each of which unique from the last. At bare minimum, this group of arrays has 1 array for every possible combination for the number of elements in the array. For example, if it was a 2x2 array, there would be 16 different arrays. The main problem I encounter when doing this is in how I wish to order them. I need them ordered like this: each array is grouped with other arrays that have the same number of true boolean values (or 1's if you want base 2). Within those groups, order the arrays by arrays that start with the same values. This is really hard to explain over text, so I'll write an example of every 2D array for 2x2...

```
[[00],[00]] [[10],[00]] [[01],[00]] [[00],[10]] [[01],[00]] [[11],[00]] [[10],[10]] [[10],[01]] [[01],[10]] [[01],[01]] [[00],[11]] [[11],[10]] [[11],[01]] [[10],[11]] [[01],[11]] [[11],[11]]
```

As you can see, it starts with 0 1's, then 4 arrays with 1 1's, then 6 arrays with 2 1's (starting with the 1st 1 on the first slot with the 2nd shifting through the remaining 3, then the first on the second slot with the 2nd shifting through the remaining 2 etc.) etc. all the way through 4 1's. Side note: the end goal of this program will actually be to have 512 3x3 arrays, I just used 2x2 here for simplicity.

Right now I've created a 4D array with a method that returns a single 2D array from that 4D array given 2 parameters which serve as the 4th and 3rd dimensions. The first in the 4th I've let represent the arrays grouped by number of 1's, the second in the 3rd just indexes which 2D array to return.

I didn't include the actual code because I know it works, and its not really relevant to the question as I haven't actually generated the 2D arrays yet.